# OpenID extension for MediaWiki install fails?! table openid_users not found

Tags: openid, installation, mediawiki

I am trying to install the OpenID extension for MediaWiki. Using Dreamhost I one-clicked installed MediaWiki 1.16.4, setup the software, and then proceeded to follow the instructions listed here:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OpenID#Installation

The pre-requisites were listed in the php config path as shared. As far as I can remember the OpenID installation goes fine until step 5 when I try to run update.php

It dies with the message:

```
A database query syntax error has occured.
The last attempted database query was:
"SELECT * FROM `mw_user_openid` LIMIT 1"
from within function "".
Database returned error "1146: Table 'skirt.mw_user_openid' doesn't exist (***)"
```

Well, of course it doesn't. It hasn't been created. update.php, to my understanding, is supposed to create that table but there is no indication of why it does not.

I would try creating the table myself but I can not find the SQL used to create it.

Has anyone experienced a similar situation or have any advice? I've been trying to find relevant information without success. This is a completely fresh install.

Comment: gmp was installed but not enabled. I fixed that and tried to run update.php again but it didn't help. Still no error message explaining why openid_users isn't being created successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems strage. Perhaps `update.php` doesn't have `CREATE` permissions on that database?

Anyway, here's the SQL schema you're looking for:
http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/trunk/extensions/OpenID/patches/openid_table.sql?view=markup

Naturally, you should use the one in your `extensions/OpenID/patches/` dir to ensure compatibility. Creating the table manually should get it to work.

Comment: Creating the table manually did the trick. AFAIK, everything had proper permissions. I was really confused but I guess it's an afterthought now.

Comment: Tried to use the Wiki and it said SpecialPageFactory not found line 40 in OpenID.hooks.php. So I changed it to SpecialPage and problem solved? I wonder if I have the wrong version of the OpenID extension. I just pulled the latest trunk like the instructions said?

Comment: Remember that this is not only about the extension, but rather about MediaWiki version to extension version compatibility. It may be that you're running an older MediaWiki. Try upgrading to the newest release and using the version of OpenID supplied by the "Download" feature at mediawiki.org.

Comment: Okay well i upgraded to mw 1.18 and it seems to be working, except i got an error in OpenID.hooks.php when running update.php: call to undefined method MysqlUpdater::addExtensionField(). really dont get it >.< but it seems to be working thanks tor!